# Swift function parameters as local variables

Tags: swift, function, parameters

I am learning some of the fine point of Swift. On function parameters, the documentation says:

> Function parameters are constants by default.

… and proceeds to discuss in-out parameters, which I suppose are Swift’s version of reference parameters.

In other languages, parameters behave as local variables, so you can do this with impunity:

```swift
func test(a: Int) {
    a = a + 1   //  cannot assign to a
    print(a*2)
}
var x = 3
test(x)
print(x)    //  -> 3 as before
```

I know I can easily create local variables, but is there a Swift equivalent to parameters as local variables?

**Note:**

The SO description for the `parameter` tag even uses the word “label”:

> Parameters are a type of variable used in a subroutine to refer to the data provided as input to the subroutine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before Swift 3, Swift used to have them. You *used to be able to* do something like this:

```
func f(var x: Int) { // note the "var" modifier here
    x += 1
    print(x) // prints 2
}

var a = 1
f(a)
print(a) // prints 1
```

But it was removed in Swift 3, via [SE-0003](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0003-remove-var-parameters.md). The Swift community decided that this is not a good feature. The motivations given in that proposal are:

> - `var` is often confused with `inout` in function parameters.
> - `var` is often confused to make value types have reference semantics.
> - Function parameters are not refutable patterns like in if-, while-, guard-, for-in-, and case statements.

Comment: That clears it up. I’m not too sure about the justification, since I’ve never seen it as a problem in any other language. In any case, as the linked document says, I can always shadow it with something like `var a = a + 1` in my example, or `let` if there are no further mutations. Thanks

Comment: @Manngo um why would you use `let` to shadow it? If there are no mutations, just use the parameter directly!

Comment: That’s probably true. Certainly in this trivial case.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understood what do you try to achieve, but if you want to modify external `x` (so it would be not *3 as before*), then you have to make function parameter as `inout`:

```
func test(_ a: inout Int) {
    a = a + 1   //  no error anymore
    print(a*2)
}
var x = 3
test(&x)
print(x)    //  -> 4
```

[image: demo]

**Update:**

```
func test(_ a: Int) {
    var a = a // make read-write
    a = a + 1
    print(a*2)
}
var x = 3
test(x)
print(x)    //  -> 3 as before
```

[image: demo2]

Comment: In other languages I can modify `a` within the function without having an effect on the `x` outside. This is because the `a` is a local variable with a copy of `x`.